# React Native - Undo the deleted app in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm building a react-native app and accidentally deleted the app from the simulator. Even after running `react-native run-ios`, although the simulator is starting the icon for the app is missing. How can this be brought back? 
I tried searching for .app file to drag and drop into the simulator, but could not find it inside my project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to run the app from X-Code.

I always do `react-native start` and then start the app from X-Code

Comment: I have few build errors to fix. That's why I'm trying with `react-native run-ios`  to see the screen.

Comment: You'll see the build errors more clearly in XCode if they are native ones. It's only really useful for that when building. Otherwise, `react-native run-ios` is fine for most situations.

Comment: I'd try to fix build errors in xcode... What kind of errors do you get?